# Showing how to find the vertices of the circle.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning

Find that the circle has four vertices.

$$\gamma (t)=\langle R\cos (t/R), R \sin (t/R)\rangle$$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$

---

I know the theorem:

Every simple closed convex curve has atleast four vertices.

Comment: What is a verticle?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534329/how-to-find-verticles-of-a-circle

Comment: Okay, I deleted it because of No answer, and I have asked again with more information. What is the problem ? @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been through similar things with you before. A vertex is a critical point of the curvature of a plane curve. Since the curvature of a circle is constant, *every* point of a circle is a vertex.